# Why chrome remove wrong css class?

Tags: css, google-chrome

browser: Chrome 60.0.3112.78

Original:

```
CSSRuleList {0: CSSStyleRule, 1: CSSStyleRule, 2: CSSStyleRule, 3: CSSStyleRule, length: 4}
      length:4
  0:CSSStyleRule {selectorText: ".highlight", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, type: 1, cssText: ".highlight { background-color: rgb(182, 246, 156); }", parentRule: null, …}
  1:CSSStyleRule {selectorText: ".highlight:hover", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, type: 1, cssText: ".highlight:hover { background-color: rgb(124, 208, 124); }", parentRule: null, …}
  2:CSSStyleRule {selectorText: ".highlightb6f69c:hover", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, type: 1, cssText: ".highlightb6f69c:hover { background-color: rgb(124, 208, 124); }", parentRule: null, …}
  3:CSSStyleRule {selectorText: ".highlightb6f69c", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, type: 1, cssText: ".highlightb6f69c { background-color: rgb(182, 246, 156); }", parentRule: null, …}
```

Operation:

```
> document.getElementById('styles').sheet.removeRule('.highlightb6f69c')

<- undefined

> document.getElementById('styles').sheet.rules

<- CSSRuleList {0: CSSStyleRule, 1: CSSStyleRule, 2: CSSStyleRule, 3: CSSStyleRule, length: 3}
      length:3
  0:CSSStyleRule {selectorText: ".highlight:hover", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, type: 1, cssText: ".highlight:hover { background-color: rgb(124, 208, 124); }", parentRule: null, …}
  1:CSSStyleRule {selectorText: ".highlightb6f69c:hover", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, type: 1, cssText: ".highlightb6f69c:hover { background-color: rgb(124, 208, 124); }", parentRule: null, …}
  2:CSSStyleRule {selectorText: ".highlightb6f69c", style: CSSStyleDeclaration, type: 1, cssText: ".highlightb6f69c { background-color: rgb(182, 246, 156); }", parentRule: null, …}
```

I want to remove the class `.highlightb6f69c`, but Chrome remove `.highlight` instead, why?

The screenshot
[image]

Comment: Looks like removeRule (Or at least deleteRule, from what I can find on MDN) takes a index, not a name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule

The CSSStyleSheet.deleteRule() method removes a style rule from the current style sheet object.

**Syntax**

```
stylesheet.deleteRule(index)
```

Parameters
index is a long number representing the position of the rule.

So, the reason the wrong rule is removed is because of `.highlightb6f69c` is parsed as `0` or NaN, removing the first one.